# Strange Java Math Result

Tags: java, math

Really simple question but perhaps someone can explain.  I have 2 lines of code:

```
long millisPerYear = 365*24*60*60*1000;
System.out.println("millis per year = " + millisPerYear);
```

I expect the output of 31 536 000 000 but I get 1 471 228 928.

If I remove the 1000 from the formula the answer is correct but the 1000 pushes it over the edge.

The variables format is `Long` so it should be 2<sup>64</sup> in size, plenty big enough. I'm stumped as to why the values isn't being stored accurately.

Comment: Your variable is `long`, that's true. But think about it: are the numbers you multiply `long` too?

Comment: You can avoid such explicit multiplications for time units by using the `TimeUnit` class: `long millisPerYear = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(365);`

Comment: @AndyTurner And of course in real life millisecond accuracy doesn't make sense on this scale, as there is a different number of milliseconds in every year. Oh, and there are at least 3 different, but equally valid definitions for "year". We usually don't have to worry about it, as the difference between them is a matter of minutes, but if you want millisecond precision, suddenly they become important.

Comment: @biziclop I did consider naming the variable `millisPer365_24_hour_days_with_no_leap_seconds`...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are making computation on the right-hand side using only `int`s. Replace `365` with `365L` to perform computation in `long`.